# Auto replacement of variable types in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Hi: I'm using intellij IDEA. when I declare a variable type as

**String** string ="example";

when I close the project and open it again , it is automatically show as

**val** string ="example";

this happens with all of the variable types automatically, then I need to click on val to revert it back to String.
Can someone guide me how to disable this feature permanently ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have "Advanced Java Folding" plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9320-advanced-java-folding) installed. As its description states, its features can be disabled in "Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding".